# Visual C++ hide Scrollbar

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, scrollbar

I am trying to hide my scrollbars in Mainframe windows so that all views will not display the vertical and horizontal bars. Here is the code.

```
void CMainFrame::OnPaint()
{
  CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
  // TODO: Add your message handler code here
  // Do not call CFrameWndEx::OnPaint() for painting messages
  ShowScrollBar(SB_BOTH, FALSE);
#pragma comment(lib, "UxTheme.lib")
 if (IsThemeActive()) ::SetWindowTheme(*this, NULL, _T("Scrollbar"));
}
```

I cannot make this work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it a requirement to call `ShowScrollBar` from the `OnPaint` event ? It seems weird to me. Have you tried to call it from `OnCreate` instead ?

Also, from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787601(v=vs.85).aspx it says that visual artifacts can be left when hiding scrollbars. Are the scrollbars you see visual artifacts, or are you still able to click and use them ?

Comment: I used the code segments in many places. The result is all the same. It seems visual artifacts. There is a grid control inside the CView. I do not want to have double vertical scroll bars.

Comment: It was my mistake. I have the following the CView.BOOL CDrugView::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
 cs.style |= WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL ; 
 return CView::PreCreateWindow(cs);
} I need to delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the child view CView. Somehow, the MFC default creates PreCreateWindow function and implements horizontal and vertical scroll bars. I did not notice the problem before I posted the question.